# Return length of a parsed json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, bson

I have an array of objects that i get from a json file. After getting the array with fs.readFileSync.

```
jsonData = JSON.stringify(fs.readFileSync('data.json'.toString(), 'utf8'));
parsedJsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

and when I do:

```
console.log(parsedJsonData);
```

it returns: 710, instead of what i expect to be 1

here is the array(with only one object)

```
[
{
    "email": "ibrahim.m.fadel@gmail.com",
    "username": "ibrahim fadel",
    "password": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "data": [
            25,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            2,
            115,
            116,
            114,
            105,
            110,
            103,
            0,
            8,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            99,
            97,
            114,
            101,
            121,
            51,
            49,
            0,
            0
        ]
    },
    "id": 0
}
]
```

I simply want to find the amount of objects that there are in the array, which is 1 so I can loop through it

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sounds like your `myArray` might just be the string representation - try calling `JSON.parse` on it first?

Comment: I did parse the array.
jsonData = JSON.stringify(fs.readFileSync('data.json'.toString(), 'utf8'));
parsedJsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

when I do for example:
return parsedJsonData.length it returns 704

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unnecessary `JSON.stringify()` over a string is causing problems, look at this:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify("[\n" +    "{\n" +    "    \"email\": \"ibrahim.m.fadel@gmail.com\",\n" +    "    \"username\": \"ibrahim fadel\",\n" +    "    \"password\": {\n" +    "        \"type\": \"Buffer\",\n" +    "        \"data\": [\n" +    "            25,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            2,\n" +    "            115,\n" +    "            116,\n" +    "            114,\n" +    "            105,\n" +    "            110,\n" +    "            103,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            8,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            99,\n" +    "            97,\n" +    "            114,\n" +    "            101,\n" +    "            121,\n" +    "            51,\n" +    "            49,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0\n" +    "        ]\n" +    "    },\n" +    "    \"id\": 0\n" +    "}\n" +    "]"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Is returning a escaped string, so when you call the function `JSON.parse()` this function actually is returning a string:

```js
console.log(typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("[\n" +    "{\n" +    "    \"email\": \"ibrahim.m.fadel@gmail.com\",\n" +    "    \"username\": \"ibrahim fadel\",\n" +    "    \"password\": {\n" +    "        \"type\": \"Buffer\",\n" +    "        \"data\": [\n" +    "            25,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            2,\n" +    "            115,\n" +    "            116,\n" +    "            114,\n" +    "            105,\n" +    "            110,\n" +    "            103,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            8,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            99,\n" +    "            97,\n" +    "            114,\n" +    "            101,\n" +    "            121,\n" +    "            51,\n" +    "            49,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0\n" +    "        ]\n" +    "    },\n" +    "    \"id\": 0\n" +    "}\n" +    "]")))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The solution is removing the call of `JSON.stringify`

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("[\n" +    "{\n" +    "    \"email\": \"ibrahim.m.fadel@gmail.com\",\n" +    "    \"username\": \"ibrahim fadel\",\n" +    "    \"password\": {\n" +    "        \"type\": \"Buffer\",\n" +    "        \"data\": [\n" +    "            25,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            2,\n" +    "            115,\n" +    "            116,\n" +    "            114,\n" +    "            105,\n" +    "            110,\n" +    "            103,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            8,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            99,\n" +    "            97,\n" +    "            114,\n" +    "            101,\n" +    "            121,\n" +    "            51,\n" +    "            49,\n" +    "            0,\n" +    "            0\n" +    "        ]\n" +    "    },\n" +    "    \"id\": 0\n" +    "}\n" +    "]")
.length)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: When I remove the stringify:

jsonData = fs.readFileSync('data.json'.toString(), 'utf8');
parsedJsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

and console.log(parsedJsonData)

i get an error because of the parse: unexpected end of json input

Do you know the cause?